# Transparent activity on lock screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, transparent, lockscreen

I'm trying to show a transparent activity on home and lock screen. When unlocked (in home screen) it is shown correctly as transparent but on lock screen there is a black background. How can I get rid of this black background?
Thanks

Style definition:

```
    <style name="MyActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest definition:

```
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
            android:theme="@style/MyActivityTheme"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"/>
    </application>
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="My Activity"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a translucent `theme` to avoid a black screen at locked state. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` use `android:theme="android:style/Theme.Translucent"` in your `<activity` or `<application>`.

Comment: I tried this, too but no help. Besides Theme.Translucent is not allowed when using AppCompatActivity and there is no equivalent of appcompant like  Theme.AppCompat.Translucent